# How do I print text and a variable in Python 3? (Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that in Python 3, `print` is now a function.

However, I have two variables that I wish to include in a print function.

`foo = 5`

`fee = 3`

The following gives an error:

`print('Foos present:' + foo, 'Fees present:' + fee)`

`TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly`

Comment: Try explicit conversion: 

print('Foos present:' + str(foo), 'Fees present:' + str(fee))

Comment: That worked. Thanks.

Comment: The real solution here isn't to use `str` to force your variable values into strings. It's to remove the `+` signs and replace them with commas. `print('A' + B)` is trying to print the **sum** of A and B. Using `print('A', B)` means print the text A then the variable B.